# "Install" option is not appearing in ubuntu software center in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: system-installation, 13.04

Recently I installed Ubuntu 13.04 (x64 bit) and I am new to Linux. In "Ubuntu software center" the right side "install" button is disappearing when I am trying to install software. Instead of "Install" button "Use this source" button is appearing.

"Install" button was appearing previously, but not now.

already tried with below two commands, still "install" button is not appearing.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Please help me how can I get back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in the following case, please correct me if I am wrong:

For most programs you do see a “Install” button. Try for instance for The Gimp or for VLC.

For some particular programs, you cannot install it right away. This is probably the case for Flash or for Oracle Java, for instance. This is because you have to activate the partners' repositories.

To do this, please click on “Use this source”, then “Install should appear”. Maybe you have to relaunch the Software Center. Another method is to launch a program called “Software & Updates”. There, go to the “Other Software” tab and check both “Independent” and “Canonical Partners”.

I hope it works!

Comment: thank you Agmenor. "Install" button is not appearing even for "Gimp" and "VLC" also. If i click on "Use this source" button "Not found" is appearing. I have enabled  both "Independent" and "Cononical Partners" in "Softwares & Updates" than updated. even it not appearing. Finally i reinstaled "Ubuntu Software Center", same problem repeating.

Comment: i got new problem now, when ever i run command "sudo apt-get install software center" from terminal this massage showing. ramesh@ramesh-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo apt-get install software-center    
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)     
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Answer (score 0):

You may have done it before, but try rebooting your computer, then install something in the command line, for instance:

```
sudo apt-get install sl
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your mirror may help.

Search for the Synaptic Package Manager on the Dash Home.

Once you are in it, navigate to the Settings menu. Click on Repositories and then Ubuntu Software. Then, select a new mirror.

[(Src)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)